# Remove unnecessary tags in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do I get rid of useless end tags in notepad++ such as Grade/ or Pick_Printer/ that contain no information without disrupting lines that hold values. I've been trying find and replace but haven't had much luck. Thanks!

```
<TRANSACTION_CODE>RC</TRANSACTION_CODE>
<CUST_NAME/>
<DESTINATION>STRM 00Z</DESTINATION>
<FINAL_DEST/>
<FINAL_DEST_TYPE/>
<UNIT_EXPIRED/>
<GRADE/>
<GROUP_ID/>
<PICK_PRINTER/>
<OPERATOR_INITIALS>PT1</OPERATOR_INITIALS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex search string to search for the useless tags, and replace with nothing (BLANK)

```
<.*/>(\r\n)
```

For Regex, you'll have to select Regular Expression before search-replace. And also, uncheck . matches new line.

Here's an image of the regex feature.

[image: Regex]